# How can I predict the nutrients in dishes given the ingredients used to prepare them?

Tags: machine-learning, ai-design, applications, prediction

I want to know which algorithm will work most efficiently for calculating nutrients present in a food dish if I am giving the ingredients used in the food. Basically, let us assume that I want to make a health status for a person A based on the intake of food and based on it create a diet for him.

Comment: Welcome to AI.SE. What have you researched on the topic? If you include the rough process of how food value is actually measured then you might get a solution, otherwise I don't think anyone here is an expert on nutrition related stuff. By Algorithm do you mean AI related algorithms only? Because many other algos might perform better.

Comment: @DuttaA we are using a weighing scale which weighs the ingredients before cooking food. Based on it, I want to calculate the nutrients content. Like a particular vegetable has x amount of vitamin A but after boiling it, it drop downs to A - Z. So this A - Z needs to be updated to a specific person's data and use it to calculate how healthy he is and based on it create a diet for him.